# Как сделать днамическую считку высоты/ширины экрана (если пользователь к примеру перевернет телефон)

Tags: javascript, iphone

У меня некоторые блоки устанавливают позицию в зависимости от размеров экрана пользователя, но когда тестирую с Google Chrome, при повороте экрана остаются старые значения и блоки отображаются некорректно. Есть ли событие, которые считывает поворот экрана?

Comment: А вы тестировали на реальном iphone?

Comment: нет пока вот решил сразу спросить чтобы не было проблем потом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас размер элементов высчитывается скриптами, то эти скрипты нужно вешать на событие resize, которое срабатывает при повороте экрана.

При "повороте экрана" в эмуляторе Google Chrome событие resize срабатывает.

Comment: да? просто я в скрипте вычеслияю размеры в самом начале и записываю в переменные, они будут изменяться сами при повороте?

Comment: Естественно, нет. Я в своем ответе говорил про css и media-запросы.

Comment: ааа, ну у меня в скрипте всё это

Comment: Дополнил ответ - вам тогда скрипты надо вешать на событие resize

Comment: @KAGGDesign а с чего вы решили, что в эмуляре при смене ориентации устройства resize не срабатывает?

Comment: @Cheg я как раз написал, что resize срабатывает. А проблема (причем в прошлых версиях) была с медиа-запросами), Посмотрел старый сайт, на котором видел проблему - сейчас все нормально.

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, извиняюсь. невнимательно прочитал

Comment: @Cheg убрал из ответа воспоминания об устаревшем приколе эмулятора Хром.